# How to load a extjs 5 app in a jsp view - Spring MVC?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, extjs5

I dont find any information about extjs 5 and Spring mvc. I had generate a extjs app inside my resources folder in my maven project.

Now, i need to load the app in my jsp view. What are the resources i need to load in my jsp view?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `.js` files should be in `/webapp/static/scripts` or similar.

You should use a default servlet handler (in your web application context config, usually `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`):

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

and

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" />
```

ExtJS is just a JavaScript library. You would load it as you would any other JavaScript, by adding a `<script src='some-path'>` tag in HTML.

In a JSP, you should use a `<c:url value='some-path'/>` taglib so that you don't have to hard-code your context. So it should look like this:

```
<script src="<c:url value='/static/scripts/myApp.js'/>"></script>
```

You should use Sencha's cmd tool to combine ExtJS files and your application files into one javascript file. You will also need to reference ExtJS's CSS using a `<link>` tag.

Comment: My app is already loading the static files but if you check the index.hmtl of extjs 5 app, only the resource bootstrap.js is loaded. I can load this file but after, other files are loaded and failed because dont find these files

Comment: @VítorNóbrega are you getting a 404 error? Can you see the js file in the browser by directly going to its url? try absolute paths for testing, then try to figure out why it can't find.